# How to register test number when using WhatsApp Business API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I'm trying to send test message on WhatsApp Business API
it took a day until I was shown a test number on "from" option
now I need to register the test phone but don't know how.

[image]

the register link take me to the configuration page,
but there is no option to register

[image]

Here is my WhatsApp account:
[image]

Comment: So where does that "register" link take you to?

Comment: @CBroe see my second picture

Comment: any news on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add any testing phone numbers, Facebook App by default provides one, that you can see in **From** dropdown,

You can add only productions phone numbers, follow the below ways,

You can find the option in your Facebook App > Getting Started under WhatsApp menu,

[image]

Second, you can add from Your Business Setting,

[image]

Read more about how to register a phone number in WhatsApp Business,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/phone-numbers

Comment: correct but this for production number, i'm ask about testing number that I get while creating the app

Comment: You can't add any testing business number, by default Facebook app provide one, that you an see in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this, it seems to be a bug in facebook itself or some lock in relation verified business, I did a test by creating a new business account and also a new application for this account , I activated whatsapp business and everything worked perfectly. But when I try to do the same procedure with an already verified account, the test number requests some kind of registration and also sends a notification that the test number was not approved. Unfortunately I haven't found any solution for this yet.

[notification refused number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rVhv.png)